# How to know which Google Apps Script API is the reason for a scope?

Tags: permissions, google-oauth, scopes, google-apps-script-addon, google-apps-script-api

**Background:** I'm the creator of [PlantUML Gizmo](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/plantuml_gizmo/1009735747823), one of the first Google Docs add-ons. As such, it's a kind of legacy add-on, and I began the development long before there were today's processes of managing OAuth 2.0 scopes and consent (which are still evolving it seems). At one point I had to even migrate it to G Suite Marketplace, so I'm not entirely sure what the process of creating a new Add-on today would be like.

A few weeks ago I got an email from Google saying I must "Submit your apps’ sensitive scopes for OAuth API verification" before a certain date, which I'm trying to respect now.

Here is the list of scopes I see:

[image: List of scopes for Google APIs]

Two of them surprise me, namely email and profile. My add-on does not use these things directly, so I never (to the best of my knowledge) requested these scopes.

On the other hand, I remember that, in the early days, my add-on would request a permission of "Allow this application to run when you are not present" (see the [list of permissions](https://sites.google.com/site/plantumlgizmo/privacy-policy)). The explanation I got from a Google employee (or on Google+ forums that are now dead) that it was due to OAuth tokens being refreshed when you're off line. I never explicitly do anything in my code to run when users are not present!

So my question is to know why `email` and/or `profile` scope are required in my add-on as it's configured. I can easily delete those scopes today, but I'm afraid to break some functionality.

Clicking on `Learn more` in the Scopes page takes me to a long list of APIs. I can find the `email` scope on this page and it says only:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email       View your email address

I didn't explicitly request that scope. How can I know if it's coming from an API call (e.g., saving preference data, etc.)? The same goes for the `profile` scope.

p.s. I have always found it frustrating as a user (developer) to know which features (API calls) require which permissions/scopes. I have always wanted transparency (and to provide it as a developer).

Comment: The scope required by each call is detailed in the Apps Script documentation. You could also manually set the scopes in your manifest file, execute your add-on, and see where it breaks

Comment: Following instructions on [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes), I find that the project scopes are 3 OAuth Scopes required by the script:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request -- no mention of profile or email. I guess I can remove those, at least from the GAS perspective.